# Stereo baseline between two frames

Tags: arcore

I am trying to calculate the stereo baseline (possibly in cm) between two arbitrary frames, after a 6DoF tracking has being performed. I would like to extract further additional information by comparing two frames but I need somehow to figure out what is the distance between the camera position in frame 1 and, say frame 10. Any suggestion on how to proceed?

I have done this in a more explicit and non-automated way with a 3D tracking software that solves the camera, then I physically measure the distance of the solved camera on frame 1 and 10 but I'm stuck conceptually on how to do this in ArCore

Comment: I am not sure if you use Android or Unity but it is quite simple in both. In Unity you can just use the position of first person camera under ARCore device and in Android there is a function called `getDisplayOrientedPose ()`. Finding the frame count is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thanks @AliKanat I also found that in the ARCore API there is a Camera class and a getPose() method that seems to be able to give me the data I need about the camera position. Then I guess it would be a matter of calculating the distance between the two positions in 3D space, right?

Comment: I believe that is the case based on what i understood from what story baseline is. I am certain that i will give you the distance between positions of the camera in two different frames though.

Comment: @AliKanat yes that is what the stereo baseline is, I'm only wondering whether it's x1 - x, y1 - y, z1 - z or it's only x1 - x as per horizontal baseline. I'll try this out this evening and update with my findings, but thank you very much for the replies

Comment: actually it should be two `Vector3`so you would just subtract them and . If you want the distance then you can calculate the magnitude.